# What is the name of this font type?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I like the font used in this paper, but don't know its name.

https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w25136/w25136.pdf

Can someone tell me (1) what is the name of the main font used in the paper, and (2) what is the name of the math font?

Thanks so much.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Font in the top (Cover and Abstract) is Times New Roman.

[image]

and the rest is URW Palladio, check this [page on Font Catalogue](http://tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwpalladio/) for details on setting it up.

[image]

Comment: For clarification (mostly my own, but good for any others reading this: how did you find that? I clicked to inspect the element in Chrome and found only font-family: Roboto, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif; (though a belated check in Firefox revealed Times New Roman — I didn't bother checking other browsers).

Comment: AdobeReader mentions 26 fonts in all – but not Roboto, Segoe UI, Tahoma, making 11 families in all.

Answer (score 2):

The document seems to have been typeset with `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` and `\usepackage{eurosym}`. The key to see this is to notice PazoMath and URWPalladio in the list below.

If I run `pdffonts` on the mentioned PDF file, I get

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Roman                          Type 1            Custom           no  no  no     812  0
GOANIB+TimesNewRomanPSMT             CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes   1447  0
Times-Roman                          Type 1            Custom           no  no  no     814  0
Times-Bold                           Type 1            Custom           no  no  no     813  0
TIAHIJ+URWPalladioL-Roma             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     827  0
YMHWWR+TeXPalladioL-SC               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     833  0
TFCFSM+URWPalladioL-Ital             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     817  0
CWFANG+URWPalladioL-Bold             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     830  0
EZZFBZ+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     838  0
RMTBLR+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     822  0
PZJBPW+PazoMath-Italic               Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     840  0
YXAIJA+CMEX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     845  0
IKXQUG+PazoMath                      Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     847  0
SYFPBV+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     856  0
PMAHJP+Cambria                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    242  0
PMAHJP+Cambria                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    246  0
PMAJIE+Cambria-Bold                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    248  0
PMAJJF+Cambria-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     249  0
PMAHJP+Cambria                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    284  0
PMAHJP+Cambria                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    291  0
PMAJIE+Cambria-Bold                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    293  0
PMAJJF+Cambria-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no     294  0
KCXMNX+TeX-feymr10                   Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     870  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    350  0
AOXMDY+Arial                         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    353  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    382  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    386  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    408  0
FASWVE+Arial                         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    411  0
Verdana                              TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  yes    414  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    423  0
DXCAMN+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    431  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    471  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    484  0
IQGWEN+Arial                         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    487  0
ArialMT                              TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  yes    509  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    513  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    531  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    535  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Custom           no  no  no     547  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Custom           no  no  no     550  0
CHNQZQ+URWPalladioL-BoldItal         Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     885  0
HUQVCB+CMBX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     886  0
QRESJF+CMBSY10                       Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     887  0
TIQFNQ+PazoMath-BoldItalic           Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     888  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    582  0
OSSDMB+Calibri-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    594  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    685  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    699  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    703  0
GWHDZV+CMTI10                        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     715  0
EZZFBZ+CMR10                         Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     719  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    729  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    733  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    745  0
GJOTKG+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    748  0
ANVQNS+Arial                         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    751  0
XYHASJ+Arial                         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    754  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    762  0
PGLCUZ+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    765  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    769  0
YAAJCC+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    772  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    776  0
MLAILV+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    779  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    783  0
DVICKR+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    786  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    792  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    798  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    806  0
HPDFAA+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    810  0
```

Times, Helvetica, Calibri, Verdana, Cambria and Arial are from the embedded images and the initial pages (that has Times in some variation). There are also Computer Modern fonts, probably due to embedded images as well.

The `feymr10` font is the Euro symbol from the package `eurosym`.